# How to delete a tuple from a list of tuples, if the first value of tuple a duplicate of another tuplee

Tags: python, set, tuples

I need to delete the tuple from a list of tuples, if the first value of the tuple is duplicate of another tuple. For example this is a list of tuples

```
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
 ('genera', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Region'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Region'),
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
 ('Islands',28,'https://en.wikipedia.org dddfdfdf/wiki/'),
 ('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
 ('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
 ('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
 ('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
```

The output must be like this:

```
 ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
 ('genera', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus'),
 ('Islands',28,'https://en.wikipedia.org dddfdfdf/wiki/'),
 ('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island')
```

I'm trying everything what search in web

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
In short, we cannot fix code you failed to post.

Comment: Why `/Auckland`, and not `/Auckland_Airport` or `/Auckland_Region`? Does the first or the last occurrence win? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Have you tried using a dictionary, where the first item of each tuple is used as key, and the rest as value?

Comment: Only first value is have matter

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You question mentioned a **list** of tuples. Therefore, I'm assuming your list looks something like this:

```
all =[('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
('genera', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Region'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Region'),
('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
('Islands',28,'https://en.wikipedia.org dddfdfdf/wiki/'),
('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island')]
```

If that's the case, the easiest way to get unique results based on the first value, is to change the list of tuples into a set (always unique and saves possibly many needless iterations in the following for loop) and then loop this way:

```
unique_all = list(set(all))
first_values = []
for t in unique_all:
    if t[0] in first_values:
        unique_all.remove(t)
    else:
        first_values.append(t[0])

print(unique_all)
```

The output will be:

```
[('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport'),
 ('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island'),
 ('genera', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus'),
 ('Islands', 28, 'https://en.wikipedia.org dddfdfdf/wiki/')]
```

I assume that's what your question asked for.

Comment: The OP wanted to eliminate tuples that share the same value at the 0 index, not just remove tuples that are identical in every value of the tuple, which is what your solution is achieving.

Comment: You're right...seems that I misread the question. I'll edit the answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through your list and add your tuple to a new list whenever a unique tuple[0] is encountered.

```
l = [your list from above]    
uniques = set()
new_l = []
for tup in l:
    if tup[0] not in uniques:
        new_l.append(tup)
        uniques.add(tup[0])
print(new_l)
```

output:

```
[('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'), 
('genera', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus'), 
('Islands', 28, 'https://en.wikipedia.org dddfdfdf/wiki/'), 
('South Island', 29, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Island')]
```

If you really want to delete in place, perhaps a list is not the best data structure to hold it, as deleting from the middle of the list is O(n) operation as opposed to deleting from the end or appending is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

take all this in list..like

```
     l = [('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland'),
     ('genera', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus'),
     ('Auckland', 23, 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_Airport')]
```

...

now type this:

```
k = []
m = []
for i in l :
    if i[0] in k :
        pass 
    else :
        k.append([i[0]])
        m.append(i)
    print(m)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run, has multiple errors. `1=1` is not a valid operation, to assign a value to an rvalue. Maybe you meant `pass`? Also `k = k + i[0]` doesn't make sense, `k` is a list and `i[0]` is a str, so concatenating those two will produce a TypeError.

Comment: wait let me rewrite it @ Endyd

Comment: Please post it if you are able to run it on your machine and can verify it solves the problem. You've fixed the 1=1 problem but have not fixed the concatenation of list with a str.

Comment: just 2 minutes please i am going to run on my machine @Endyd

Comment: just copy and paste  it